# Efficient way to query a table with data from another table using 3 keys

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have Table A and Table B. Both tables contain about 500,000 records. Cat, Dog and Mouse house the same exact data type for both tables but data present in one table may not be in the other.

Table Zoo:

```
Cat | Dog | Mouse | Bird
xyz   dfg    sdhf   123
dfr   kjf    asdc   456
zxc   abc    qwrt   789
```

Table Pet_Store:

```
Cat | Dog | Mouse | Pig
ghf   dsa    dfre   12
dfr   gfr    qwy5   19
zxc   abc    dfgr   21
```

Desired Result:

```
  Cat | Dog | Mouse
  dfr   kjf   asdc
  zxc   abc   qwrt
```

I want to query every record where either Cat, Dog or Mouse are the same. There is no unique key here to connect both tables the only way we can draw a connection is with those 3 fields. If at least one match is present return Cat, Dog and Mouse. I did a select statement myself but considering the data I am working with is very large this process is taking a long time so I don't think I am being efficient. Any suggestions?:

```
select n.Cat, n.Dog, n.Mouse
from Zoo n, Pet_Store t
where
(n.Cat =t.Cat or n.Dog =t.Dog or n.Mouse =t.Mouse)
```

edit: Sorry I should have included a little more clarity. My brain is fried at the moment so I apologize for that. If any of the fields I do a check on match, pull the fields Cat, Dog, Mouse from the Zoo table.

Comment: do you have any indexes at all?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help me understand the question.

Comment: Sorry guys I made some edits above hopefully for a little better clarity

Comment: Your statement isn´t wrong.I think you should overthink the structure of the tables :(

Comment: Not my tables I am forced to work with them unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much you care about duplicates, you could do something like

```
select z.cat, z.dog, z.mouse from zoo z inner join pet_store p on z.cat   = p.cat
union all
select z.cat, z.dog, z.mouse from zoo z inner join pet_store p on z.dog   = p.dog
union all
select z.cat, z.dog, z.mouse from zoo z inner join pet_store p on z.mouse = p.mouse
```

This will allow index usage on all columns (assuming you have the proper indexes on both tables).

Comment: In this case, don't we want the distinct from the union vs union all?  Consider: `zxc   abc    qwrt` would be repeated as it matches on both cat and dog

Comment: Not sure - that is why I said "depending on how much you care about duplicates". `union all` will be faster but may produce duplicates; it depends on how the output is consumed. Also, the base tables may already contain duplicates, which perhaps should be preserved...

Answer (score -1):

Well you have not told us much but given what you have told us this is how I would do it.

```
SELECT A.Cat, A.Dog, A.Mouse
FROM Zoo A
LEFT JOIN Pet_Store B1 ON A.Cat = B1.Cat
LEFT JOIN Pet_Store B2 ON A.Dog = B2.Dog
LEFT JOIN Pet_Store B3 ON A.Mouse = B3.Mouse
WHERE COALESCE(B1.Cat, B2.Dog, B3.Mouse) IS NOT NULL
```

Since we don't know anything about the structure of the data or other information about the columns or the tables I know of no way to improve this query.  HOWEVER, if you do have any indexes at all -- this query will use them the best possible ways.

For example an index on B.Mouse could be used in this query but not used in your example query.

Comment: I gave a little more info above.

Comment: @Icebreaker -- nice to see the table names -- my answer is still the same -- no easy outs here.  If there are any indexes at all (even on columns not shown) that could help.

Comment: How can I tell if there is an index? Sorry, relational DB programming isn't my main thing I just got stuck with this.

Comment: Also when I ran above it seemed to produce many duplicate records but when I added "Distinct" records the data kinda looks good. I didn't go through it yet but the record amounts seem legit.

Comment: On table zoo Cat, Dog and Mouse are all indexed. In pet_store no indexes

Comment: Yes if you have records where there is a match on more than one of the fields Cat, Dog, or Mouse you will see duplicates

Comment: Hogan I know this might be off topic but if I wanted to do an update statement using those two tables. Say I added the column Pig to Table Zoo so I want Zoo to populate Pig from Pet_store if at least one of the 3 (cat, dog,  mouse) match how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You need to use an Update statement and then one of these queries that get the data you need to update.   I think doing 3 updates is probably better given your model but as you wish.

Comment: If I used one of these queries such as above which returns many duplicate results, would that be advisable for an update statement? Again, when I use Distinct the individual records are actually correct.

Comment: Functionally a statement with duplicates would have no impact on an update (update this field to the same value 5 times -- still same value) it will just be slower.  I'd use the distinct, just like I would exclude already updated rows if I was using 3 update statements.

Comment: @Icebreaker - that doesn't seem to make a lot of sense (referring to your UPDATE that is). You may have a row in the first table that matches a row in the second table on CAT and a different row on DOG, with different values for PIG. Which value will you put in the first table for the new PIG column?

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing really wrong with your query, you're dealing with no indexes and table scans on a reasonably large table. You will see a slight improvement by refactoring the query slightly, but you would see much more significant performance improvements by adding indexes.

```
SELECT z.Cat, z.Dog, z.Mouse
FROM Zoo z
  INNER JOIN Pet_Store p ON
    z.Cat = p.Cat OR
    z.Dog = p.Dog OR
    z.Mouse = p.Mouse
```

That will return the data you're looking for - there's no need to join the tables multiple times.

Comment: This is exactly the same as in the original question and it has a syntax error.

Comment: @Hogan it's not exactly the same, it's using an `INNER JOIN` and moves the conditions into the join and out of the `WHERE` clause. Your query involves multiple joins and introduces a `COALESCE` and a `NULL` check. Left-hand functions are inherently slow. Your query provides no performance gains at all.

Comment: I said it is the same as in **the original question**.  (not my answer)

Comment: Yes, I got that, it's not the same as the original question. I moved the conditions out of the WHERE clause and into the INNER JOIN statement. Optimizer often interprets set-based conditions (in the JOIN) earlier than the WHERE clause reducing the individual sets being joined. When you use the WHERE you first create two large sets and then restrict them. When putting conditions into the JOIN you restrict the size of the set you're joining.

It's not "exactly the same" as the original question, it (minimally) addresses the performance issue which is the intent of the question.

Comment: This is not true -- as part of the SQL standard it defines old style joins to be functionally the same as new style joins -- this is just syntax sugar with a single inner join.  You are right that there are *some cases* where moving a filter from the where to the join clause will have an impact.  This is not one of them.

Comment: If they're "identical" it's interesting then that when I create sample data and run execution plans that A: they're different and B: my version runs faster than the original (0.376s vs 0.462s)

Comment: Probably just that memory is cached did you run them back and forth 20 times or so and average the results?